# Image as link in IE9

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, image, internet-explorer-9

I have a link "`<a ... ></a>`" and within it an image ""

Something like:
"`<a...><img src.../></a>`"

My problem is in IE9 (do not know if it occurs in versions prior to IE9) that is putting an edge in the image.

In other images on my page, which has no links, this problem does not occur.

How can I take the edge off these images that have associated links

Comment: You mean a border? Try adding `a img { border: 0 }` in CSS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this CSS:

```
img{
    border: 0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about a dotted border, it's the outline IE9 applies to all links. To remove-

a:active, a:focus {
     outline: none;
    }